# Should I use sp_getapplock to prevent multiple instances of a stored procedure that conditionally inserts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2019

Hear me out! I know this use case sounds suspect, but...

I have a stored procedure which checks a table (effectively a cache) for data for a given requested ID. If it doesn't find any data for that ID, or deems it out of date, it executes a second stored procedure which will pull data from a separate database (using dynamic SQL, source DB name is based on the requested ID) and insert it into the local table. It then selects from this table.

If the data is in the table, everything returns quickly (ms), but if it needs to be brought in from the other database, it takes about 10 seconds. We're seeing race conditions where two concurrent instances check the local cache, see something is missing, and queue up sequential ingestions of the remote data into the cache. To avoid double-insertion, the cache-populating procedure will clear whatever is already there for this id, but this just means the first instance of the procedure can selecting no rows because the second instance deleted the just-inserted records before re-inserting them itself.

I think I want to put a lock around the entire procedure (checking the cache, potentially populating the cache, selecting from the cache) - although I'm open to other solutions. I think the overall caching approach has to remain on-demand though, the remote databases come and go by the hundreds, and we only want to cache the ones actually requested by reporting as-needed.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    -- Take out a lock intended to prevent anyone else modifying the cache while we're reading and potentially modifying it
    EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = '[private].[cache_entries]', @LockOwner='Transaction', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockTimeout = 120000; 

    -- Invoke a stored procedure that ingests any required data that is not already cached
    EXEC [private].populate_cache @required_dbs

    -- CALCULATIONS
    -- ... SELECT FROM [private].cache_entries
    
    COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- Free the lock
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH --Ensure we release our lock on failure
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `sp_getapplock`, which tends to inhibit concurrency a lot.

The way to do this is to continue do your checks within a transaction, but to apply a `HOLDLOCK` hint, as well as a `UPDLOCK` hint.

`HOLDLOCK` aka the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, will place a lock not only on the ID you specify, but even on the *absence* of such data, in other words it will prevent anyone else inserting into that ID.

You *must* use both these hints, as well as have an index that matches that `SELECT`, otherwise you could run into major blocking and deadlocking problems due to full table scans.

Also, you don't need a `CATCH` and `ROLLBACK`. Just use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` which ensures a rollback in any event of an error.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;   -- always have this set

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @SomeData nvarchar(100) = (
    SELECT ce.SomeColumn
    FROM [private].cache_entries ce WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE ce.SomeCondition = 1
);

IF @SomeData IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- Invoke a stored procedure that ingests any required data that is not already cached
    EXEC [private].populate_cache @required_dbs
END

-- CALCULATIONS
-- ... SELECT FROM [private].cache_entries

COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- Free the lock
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for this! In my case, I plan to insert if the cache entry is missing, or delete + insert if it is out of date. This would constitute two different where conditions. Can I safely do these in one query and get the desired result? e.g.: `DECLARE @missing_dbs TABLE(CacheId int);`   `INSERT INTO @missing_dbs SELECT R.db FROM [private].cache_entries ce WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK) RIGHT JOIN @requested_dbs R WHERE (ce.db = R.db AND ce.updated < R.updated) OR (ce.db is NULL)` - assuming I added an index to `[private].cache_entries` on the column "db"?

Comment: Yes as long as the lock is held on the same key. That query is highly suspect: there is no join condition, and a right-join could always be a left-join, and inserting a null here makes little sense, also you should always specify column names to insert into

Comment: Okay well imagine then `SELECT R.db FROM @requested_dbs R LEFT JOIN [private].cache_entries ce WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK) WHERE ...` The idea here is that there will be things missing from the cache (the table I want to lock) - so as you mentioned, the "absence" of data that I want exclusive rights to insert, but also some records that are in the table ("stale" data) that I also want locked.

Comment: Yes that should work fine, although for efficiency it's better to flip that around `SELECT R.db FROM @requested_dbs R WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [private].cache_entries ce WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK) WHERE ce.updated >= R.updated)`

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to `sp_getapplock` is to use locking hints with your transaction.  Both are reasonable approaches.  Locking hints can be complex, but they protect the target object *itself* rather than a single code path.  So sometimes necessary.  `sp_getapplock` is simple (with Transaction as owner), and reliable.